# What is the most efficient way to perform the reverse of Server.MapPath in an ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC application in which I am reading a list of files from the file system and I want to pass the relative URL to that file to the view, preferably prefixed with "~/" so that whatever view is selected cab render the URL appropriately.

To do this, I need to enumerate the files in the file system and convert their physical paths back to relative URLs.  There are a few algorithms I've experimented with, but I am concerned about efficiency and minimal string operations.  Also, I believe there's nothing in the .Net Framework that can perform this operation, but is there something in the latest MVC release that can?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At the moment I don't know any built-in method to do it, but it's not difficult, I do it like this:

- We need to get the Application root, and replace it in our new path  with `~`
- We need to convert the backslashes to slashes

---

```
public string ReverseMapPath(string path)
{
    string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
    string res = string.Format("~{0}", path.Replace(appPath, "").Replace("\\", "/"));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I have something similar right now. What I don't like is calling this in a loop for a bunch of enumerated files and all the calls to MapPath, String.Replace a String.Format.  In terms of optimization, passing in the appPath can eliminate the calls to MapPath.  Perhaps there's nothing better?!

Comment: If performance is your concern, you could have a service or something monitor the directories out of band, translate the paths to relative urls, store them somewhere, and use that data store to get the url to pass to the view.  May not be worth the trouble depending on how many files you have.

Comment: also note: if you have spaces and other characters in your filename that need encoding you may wish to add this line just before returning  the result. `res = new Uri("http://localhost" + res).AbsolutePath;`

Comment: Please note that this won't work for files in a virtual directory inside your website that points outside of the root website structure.

Comment: this method return relative path, if you need absolute path, change the starting "~" for ".."

Comment: @Matus that's still a relative path /pedant

Comment: In my case I had to change the `"~{0}"` to `"~/{0}"` (i.e. insert a `/`).

Comment: Just converting the root to a "/" won't work in every situation. -- For example when you are not the root site, "/" would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what UrlHelper.Content method does? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx

Comment: No, that helper method works with virtual paths only.  I'm looking to take an underlying physical path and map into the virtual structure of the web application.

Answer (score -2):

I did some digging, trying to get the UrlHelper class to work outside of a controller, then I remembered a old trick to do the same thing within an aspx page:

```
string ResolveUrl(string pathWithTilde)
```

Hope this helps!
See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can't figure out how to interpret this in a way that's useful ... even outside of the context of the question. -- You've given us a method signature, with no actual information about it -- is this some built-in method on an object somewhere that we should know about?

Comment: You're right, its not a concise answer. Added a link for more information.

When using WebForms, in the code-behind for an ASPX page, the ResolveURL method is made available for use.