# Cannot retrieve image from database from image path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am able to store the image path correctly in the database. But when I am trying to retrieve images in a loop in razor view, it does not show the image.
My Image path is following:

```
  C:\Users\Downloads\VisualStudio\Projects\MVC\Images\72621cb5-7266-44ac-b1cb-8a1.png
```

I can save the image in the database but I cannot retrieve it. It shows image broken icon and I have tried following code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.CustomerProfiles)
  {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.ProfileImage)" alt="Image" />
        </td>
        <td>

    </tr>
```

Also, when I inspect the image icon, and I copied the img src link which is:

```
http://localhost:53943/C:/Users/Downloads/VisualStudio/Projects/MVC/Images/72621cb5-7266-44ac-b1cb-8a1.png
```

Comment: Your image path is a file system path, and the web serves images via HTTP, so that is not going to work.

Comment: Looks like you're storing a local path rather than a relative path to your website root. You'll need to use code like [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395798/215552) to get that relative path.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How can I store the relative path? I am using this to store the image path:  obj.ProfileImage = Server.MapPath("~/Images/") +  FileName;

Comment: Remove `Server.MapPath`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you but I get an error now while saving an image using SaveAs function.  obj.ImageFile.SaveAs(obj.ProfileImage);
Error says, The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path. 
How do I save image in database with relative path then?

Comment: You're mixing two different desired results. `SaveAs` is used to save a file to the file system. The image path is used to show the file on the web site. You'll need to use `Server.MapPath` with `SaveAs`, but not when saving the path to the database.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, last question, Is there a way to resize the image automatically to thumbnail when it is showing in a list?

Comment: That's a bit more than can be said in a comment. I'm sure there are questions about that here on Stack Overflow. Do some searching; I'm sure you'll find one.